# Cannot run application in docker on Mac M1

Tags: docker, apple-m1

I have a pre-built binary and I am trying to build a docker image with the right environment that can be used to run it. My docker file has a 2 stage build as follows:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.6.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04 AS builder

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libc6 \
    build-essential

WORKDIR /build
COPY hdf5-1.14.3 /build/hdf5-1.14.3

WORKDIR /build/hdf5-1.14.3

RUN chmod +x ./configure ./bin/config.sub    # Ensure configure and config.sub scripts have executable permissions
RUN ./configure --enable-hl
RUN make -j
RUN make install


#FROM nvidia/cuda:11.6.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04

FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04

COPY --from=builder /usr/local /usr/local

COPY kspaceFirstOrder-CUDA /app/kspaceFirstOrder-CUDA
RUN chmod +x /app/kspaceFirstOrder-CUDA

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Define the command to run your application
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

This basically compiles the HD5 library and copies the app. I am running all this on my macbook pro with the M1 chip.

However, when I try and run the app, I get the following:

```
rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

 Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I installed the `libc` as well, but that does not seem to solve this. I moved to the arm base image in the second part of the build but it did not help (neither did the commented out base image)